# Disabling Spring from accepting POST params as query params

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a controller as following:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "validate", method = POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Object> validate(@Valid @ModelAttribute ValidationRequest request) {
}
```

`ValidationRequest` is a POJO with couple of fields.

With this setup, I expect this method to accept POST parameters passed **only through body of request**. However, if we make a POST request like `http://localhost:8080/validate?param1=a&param2=b` without any body, it still accepts it. I have marked all of fields inside `ValidationRequest` as mandatory.

Any suggestions? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Post your POJO `ValidationRequest` as well

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try @RequestBody instead of @ModelAttribute.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `@PathParam`.

```
@POST
@Path("/validate/{param1}/{param2}")
@Consumes({ "application/json", "text/plain" })
@Produces({ "application/json" })
public ResponseEntity<Object> validate(@Valid @ModelAttribute ValidationRequest request, 
@PathParam("param1") String param1, @PathParam("param2") String param2) {
..................
}
```